# Problem in body height in SlidingUpPanel flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Not all list are visible in body under [SlideUpPanel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel)

In list I am having 83 items but last 2~3 items are not visible

[image]

```
SlidingUpPanel(
    minHeight: 50,
    body: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-100, //No effect
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: dataBox.values.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i){
                    return ListTile(...);
                }
            )
        ),
    panel: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go into the source code of `SlidingUpPanel`, you can see that it is using the screen size to set the width and height of the body:

```dart
// Inside SlidingUpPanel's build() method:

// ... other lines
child: Container(
           height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
           width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
           child: widget.body,
       ),
// ... other lines
```

This is why when you add an AppBar and other elements in the screen, it will reposition the body but the body's height is still equal to the screen height. One workaround is to use a Stack instead of setting the `body` of the SlidingUpPanel. Something like:

```dart
@override
build(context) {
    var _collapsedHeight = 50.0;
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
            // Set the padding to display above the panel
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: _collapsedHeight),
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: dataBox.values.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i){
                  return ListTile(...);
                }
            )
        ),
        SlidingUpPanel(
          minHeight: _collapsedHeight,
          panel: Container(
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
     ],
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MediaQuery to Get the Size of the Screen then Apply this ,

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.7;
```

Comment: not working, giving height to container doesn't do anything

Comment: can u post the full page code here then i can understand the problem